# TableView Header Section Covers The Rows

Tags: xamarin, tableview, xamarin.forms

I have two questions:

1- I'm trying to do a simple table view with Xamarin forms, but i have found that the header sections cover the below cells (rows in table).

I just wants that the header section disappears like the cells when move the page and just maintain de navigation bar.

It's possible to do something like this ? Or is for default.

2- Also I'm trying to custom the size sections, I don't want the default size, i need smaller sections.

It's possible to change the sections size?

Here my table view code in XAML:

```
<TableView RowHeight = "35">
        <TableView.Root>
            <TableSection Title="EXAMPLE">     
                <CustomCell:DetailCell Text="Change password" Image ="iconPrivacy.png"></CustomCell:DetailCell>
            </TableSection>
        </TableView.Root>
</TableView>
```

Comment: Learn how to turn off capslock. There is no reason to SHOUT your title.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a `ListView` instead of a TableView. This will allow you to have the custom table headers you are looking for.

The default functionality of the headers are to "stick" under the nav bar until the next section header reaches the top.

Here is an excellent blog post on creating Grouped ListViews in Xamarin Forms:
http://motzcod.es/post/94643411707/enhancing-xamarin-forms-listview-with-grouping